# No permissions found in manifest for: []22 - Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, android-permissions

I'm trying to get storage permission from the user. Below is the sample (copy-paste) code. But I'm getting error when I'm trying to request the permission.

```
D/permissions_handler(12775): No permissions found in manifest for: []22
```

Code

```
import 'package:duplicate_file_remover/globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:duplicate_file_remover/ui/views/homeViews/homeView.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class MainDataProvider extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainDataProvider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainDataProviderState createState() => _MainDataProviderState();
}

class _MainDataProviderState extends State<MainDataProvider> {

  PermissionStatus _permissionStatus = PermissionStatus.denied;

  Future<void> _askStoragePermission() async {
    debugPrint(" ---------------- Asking for permission...");
    await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    if (await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStatus =
          await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
      setState(() {
        _permissionStatus = permissionStatus;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await _askStoragePermission();

            if (_permissionStatus.isGranted) {
              debugPrint(" ---------------- Permission allowed");
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => HomeView(),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              // openAppSettings();
              debugPrint(" --------------------- Permission denied");
            }
          },
          child: const Text("Get permission"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using `permission_handler` (https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package.

I tried [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61591788/7290043) but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Check your `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` file.

If you are using Android 11 (targetSdkVersion = 30), you will need to write this permission in `manifest` differently. You can try the solution discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366102/14266440)

Answer (score 2):

For people how experienced the issue also,

Add this permission in your manifest file under <Manifest tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
  Permission.storage,
  Permission.manageExternalStorage,
].request();

var storage = statuses[Permission.storage];
var manageExternalStorage = statuses[Permission.manageExternalStorage];
if (storage.isGranted || manageExternalStorage.isGranted) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same issue. It looks like the file_picker handles the STORAGE permission itself. So you don't need to ask this permission separately. Just use the `pickFile()` function directly and the plugin will handle the rest.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Underlying problem here could be the storage permission change Android did after v13.
So application code will need to support both permission types.

First manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then a code like below handle both flows like Even Cai has shared in their answer.

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class PermissionUtil {
  static Future<bool> tryPermission(Permission permission) async {
    var status = await permission.request();
    if (status != null) {
      if (status.isGranted) {
        print('granted');
        return true;
      } else if (status.isDenied) {
        print('requesting permission');
        status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
        if (status.isGranted) {
          print('newly granted');
          return true;
        } else {
          print('User denied ${permission.runtimeType} request'); // @fixme generalize
        }
      } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        print('permanently denied');
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}


// usage
bool permitted = await PermissionUtil.tryPermission(Permission.storage) || await PermissionUtil.tryPermission(Permission.manageExternalStorage); // for android <13 and 13+
// end
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error, I solved it by creating a new flutter project and copy my code to the new